# C++ link an extern function as member function

Tags: c++

Basically, I have an already compiled a file that is written assembly; `.obj file`. It has an exported function `f`. In C++, I wrote a class and want to use the exported function `f` as a member function.

If it were to be used as a global function, I know that one just writes`extern "C" f()`. However, this doesn't work with a member function, at least I didn't figure out how to do it.

So, how do I do it?

Note: The function `f` is written properly. i.e. it takes into account the `this` pointer, etc. It should work correctly at assembly level.

Comment: Can't you create a instance of the class? include the header file in which the class is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function is written as a free function, you will have to declare it as a free function the way you're accustomed to.  Just as you can't build a library with `void foo()` and then somehow declare it as `void bar()` and expect it to work, you can't take a free function and turn it into a member function.  What you can do, though, is add an inline forwarder into your class like so:

```
struct S;
extern "C" void f( S * );

struct S {
    void f() {
        using ::f;
        f(this);
    }
};
```

That's the best you can do, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I'd rather jus call `::f (this)`. Easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @JohnDibling:  In this case, either works fine, but I prefer to never call functions qualified because it suppresses ADL.

Comment: But that's exactly what you want in tHis case?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Since I'm in the global namespace here anyway, there is no difference.  However, I've seen many people call functions qualified in a harmful way (where ADL was desirable but nonetheless suppressed), both in example code and in production code, so I prefer to give examples that demonstrate proper ADL-aware calling.  If my structuring the code like this (where it doesn't make a difference) causes someone else to do something similar elsewhere (where it does matter and ADL is better), I feel it's worth the demonstration.  (Others may or may not agree, of course.)

Comment: Well thank you, I thought this might work in a more intelligent way, but adding a forwarder is still acceptable.

Comment: I should say that this method is fine, because the forwarder will disappear in the release version because of the optimization, so one doesn't lose anything - meanwhile it's clear and easy to maintain.